# Removing dashes in grep -A

Tags: command-line, grep

I am using `grep -A` command to get a specific pattern. It gives `--` at the end of every block, how I can remove these dashes?

Comment: I suggest you post the problem you are trying to solve, as there might be better ways to accomplish your actual goal.

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK it's not mentioned in the man page, but in the [Context Line Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Context-Line-Control) section of `info grep` you will find the option

```
‘--no-group-separator’
     When ‘-A’, ‘-B’ or ‘-C’ are in use, do not print a separator
     between groups of lines.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have [at least three alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2168065/4970442):

1. With `-v` option (works on any version of grep):

   ```
   ... | grep -A1 "pattern" | grep -v -- "^--$"
   ```

   Also, `| sed '/^--$/d'`.
2. With the undocumented `--group-separator`

   ```
   ... | grep -A1 "pattern" --group-separator ""
   ```
3. With `--no-group-separator` ([as mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/1125955/349837) steeldriver).

   ```
   ... | grep -A1 "pattern" --no-group-separator
   ```